# Emit 2 values from a redux-observable epic when source$ is a single action

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I am trying to return 2 separate values from an epic given a single source$ action. However - it seems I can only do this by explicitly subscribing to the inner Observable. My epic currently looks like this:

```
export const orderItemEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(ORDER_ITEM)
    .switchMap(action => Observable.of(
        api.createOrder(action.payload.order),
        api.updateItem(action.payload.item, action.payload.item._id)
    ))
    .map(val => console.log('Outer Observable', val));
```

However this only emits the promise of the first api request (even though both are called)

The only way I can get the two values simultaneously is to subscribe explicitly to the inner Observable Like so:

```
export const orderItemEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(ORDER_ITEM)
    .switchMap(action => Observable.of(
        api.createOrder(action.payload.order),
        api.updateItem(action.payload.item, action.payload.item._id)
    ).map(val => val).subscribe(v => console.log('Inner Observable', v))
    .map(val => console.log('Outer Observable', val)); //never gets called
```

But now my 'Outer' Observable does not get mapped.

When I mock this with JSBin it seems the first example should emit the response from both api calls. 
http://jsbin.com/cejolegixo/edit?js,console

I guess I'm just wondering if this is some quirk in redux-observable or if I am doing something incorrect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have 3 levels of Observable going on.

> this only emits the **promise** of the first api request

Your JSBin more accurately mirrors the code if you use

```js
// First Mock API
const firstAPI = res => Rx.Observable.of({...res})

// Second Mock API
const secondAPI = res => Rx.Observable.of({...res})
```

So, the fix is to 'merge' the inner observables.

```js
// map value from source into inner observable, when complete emit result and move to next
const stream = source$.switchMap(action => Rx.Observable.merge(
  firstAPI(action.payload.a),
  secondAPI(action.payload.b)
))
```

Ref [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xavelalima/1/edit?js,console)

BTW, you can `flatMap` instead of `switchMap`. Depends on the behaviour you want.

`switchMap` will cancel a first order when a second arrives while the first is progress (seems bad if they are different orders).

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your answer. Your solution still doesn't work for redux-observable though... and yes of course you are correct - my API requests are promises but your JSBin example returns exactly the same as mine... I'm wondering if I misunderstand how the actions are subscribed to under the hood in redux-observable. Will post an issue on the repo and see if they have any idea...
Also thanks for the flatMap advice but switchMap is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, scratch that... the issue was that I was just logging the output rather than firing an action. The error fired was what was blocking subsequent map functions.

Comment: You've lost me now, please explain in more detail.

Comment: Nevermind... it was my own stupid mistake :D. The original stream works correctly - it was just breaking because redux-observable requires an action as a final output. Thanks anyway.